# How can I find cells in Excel whose values are not in increments of 0.25?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet containing timekeeping data - hours worked, vacation leave, sick leave, etc.

Our policy is that all entries must be in increments of 0.25.  Due to a technical glitch, we had to 'turn off' a setting that ensures entries are in 0.25 increments.  Now, I need to find out if any of the entries are not in 0.25 increments.

Can anybody think of a formula that can search a row of data (for each employee on the spreadsheet) that will determine if any of the pay code entries within the row were not an increment of 0.25?

For example

- one row might contain 74.5 hrs worked and 5.5 vacation hours; this is okay because both values are in increments of 0.25.
- However, if someone had 74.5 hours worked and 4.87 hours of vacation, I need to find the 4.87 usage because it's not in an increment of 0.25.

Comment: `=mod(A1,.25)` - anything not 0 is off

Comment: Thank you Raystafarian!  I summed the row and then applied the 'mod' formula you provided.  Out of 2,170 rows, I only had 3 rows where employees did not use increments of 0.25 for their timecard entries.  And, this is what I needed to zero in on.  Thanks!! -Annette

Comment: @Raystafarian, could be worth moving to an answer. If he does Annette, please do mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mod](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mod.php) function to return the remainder of the sum of the rows, identifying rows you need to check.

`=Mod(A10,.25)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 type of time reported per line, you can use

```
{=SUM(MOD(B3:D3,0.25))}
```

to identify which line has an improper entry.  (you must press CTRL+Shift+Enter after typing the formula to create the array formula)

This formula assume you have:
EmployeeID in Col A, Regular Hours in Col B, Overtime Hours in Col C, and Paid Time Off in Col D.

If you have more columns, expand the range.

edit: *Formula changed per Máté's suggestion.*

Comment: Does it make sense to `sum` within `mod`? what about `{=SUM(MOD(B3:D3,0.25))}`

Comment: Doesn't (A + B + C) / .25 equal A/.25 + B/.25 + C/.25?  Either formula will work.

Comment: Mod is different than simple division, please check: `(0.1+0.15) mod 0.25` vs `0.1 mod 0.25 + 0.15 mod 0.25` !

Comment: Máté, I see your point.  Make it an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: It's your answer:), just correct it, my purpose was to help improving it.